# How to handle API credentials in an Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, laravel, api

I created an API in Laravel and I have a small SPA in Angular that logins in the app via an username & password and receive a token. With this token you can do some basic stuff with the API.

It's not ok to save the credentials (user&pass) in the Angular app (plain text - javascript etc etc). How can I handle this kind of auth in Javascript? What is a best practice?

Comment: is your token same as user&pass ?

Comment: No no. You login into the api via an username & password. After login you receive a token. The problem is with that user & pass data.

Comment: if you're getting token from API then you don't need user and pass to save anywhere on front end. Just use token in every request to authenticate user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After login, You can return the token and store in a **localstorage** for future use and refresh, and if you don't want put your token in every ajax call manually you can add to **$http** like:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + storage.token;
```

I have tried this with **angularjs** and **laravel** with this library:
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Comment: It looks nice what you have said BUT how (and where) can I do the first login? Here is the big problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, what do you mean with "I do the first login"? 
Do you have a classic login page or login form?